# Can I clone the current state of a site when running tests?

Tags: 8, testing

I would like to prove that a series of permissions defined from a module are applied to certain roles. I need to test it both on a Drupal installation done from scratch and on a Drupal installation that clones the state of an existing site.

Is this possible?

Comment: I hope I understand you right, but yes of course this is possible, under the premise that you create your testing Drupal from existing config as in `$ drush site:install --existing-config`. But what you also can do is to dump your live database, import it somewhere locally and then run `drush sql:sanitize` on it to have all the user information obfuscated and all session tables cleared, dump it again and then provide that database in your testing environment to be imported into a standard install maybe.

Comment: @leymannx When editing the question to make it clearer, I forgot a detail. The question is about module testing.

Comment: Using Behat testing will use the current database. You could also write functional tests to test if dummy users (with certain roles) can access or not access what they should. The latter will install a new database with the 'testing' profile, but you can set whatever profile you want.